# Replace '/' from string using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have string like 888-888-8888.

I want to remove all '-' from string.

How can i achieve this ? i tried below but it removes only first - .

```js
var phone = '888-888-8888';
phone = phone.replace('-', '');
alert(phone);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.replace` with a [globaly flagged](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) Regular Expression:

```js
var phone = '888-888-8888';
phone = phone.replace(/\-/g, '');
alert(phone);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `replace()` function for replacing the character occurrence from the string

```
var phone = '888-888-8888';
phone = phone.replace(/\-/g, '');
alert(phone);
```

Note that:
The `replace()` method returns a new string with some or all matches of a pattern replaced by a replacement. The pattern can be a string or a RegExp, and the replacement can be a string or a function to be called for each match. So we use `/g` for global search and replace.

```js
 var phone = '888-888-8888';
phone = phone.replace(/\-/g, '');
alert(phone);
```

Comment: I've upvoted +1 for same answer as mine but with more explenations

Answer (score 0):

Please check it,

```js
var phone = '888-888-8888';
var newphone = phone.replace(/-/g, "");
alert(newphone);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to include the [Global Flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

```
var phone = "888-888-8888";
var newPhone = phone.replace(/-/g, "");
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LjaBjq